# How to copy data from one table to other in same database?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL how to copy data from one table to another in the same database table?

I know `insert into select`, but it is taking forever to do this, especially on a live database, we can't take a risk.

Some conditions are there:
1. table1 is a source table and table1_archives is a destination table.
2. table1_archives already have data so we can only append.

My attempt:

```
time mysqldump --log-error=$logfile --complete-insert --insert-ignore 
--no-create-info --skip-triggers --user=$dbuser --host=$host $dbname table1  
--where="created < now()-interval 10 month" > $filename
```

But it has the name of table1, so I can't insert it into table1_archives.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long is forever? How often do you archive records? How many records do you archive on average?

Comment: Archival happens every weekend. 10L total records every week.

Comment: can you try workbench migration   https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/

Comment: If you check it closely, it has some condition(--where), and I will check this on one server if working fine. Then need to do the same on multiple servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your output file, you need to change the table name `table1` to `table1_archives`. Unfortunately `mysqldump` does not have any way to do this. You will have to do this on the fly using `sed`, which will rename everything in output file from `table1` to `table1_archives`.

Since your columns can also contain the content like `table1`, its better to search and replace by enclosing them in backticks.

You can also use `gzip` to compress the output file.

Here is the command that worked for me

```
mysqldump -u USER -h  HOST -p --skip-add-drop-table --no-create-info --skip-triggers --compact DB table1 |\
  sed -e 's/`table1`/`table1_archives`/' | gzip >   filename.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

"but it is taking forever to do this"

There is a small trick to avoid this and then `insert into` will work faster:

```
Insert into table1 select * from table2
```

Trick:

```
step-1: drop all indices from table2
step-2: execute query
step-3: create indices again
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, I can bet on this. I have  migrated so many huge databases using this trick. When I started it took a full day then I needed to cancel. (copying 1 million records). Then I did above, it took just 7 seconds.

Comment: "drop all indices from table2" : can you explain this : what is indices ?, drop = delete table in database , so you will delete all tables indices in table2 database ?

Comment: @Eric correct, I use to delete each index before insert and then after insert recreate them. Basically, if there is any index (other than PK obviousaly) then the insertion is slower becoming beyond our reach when the dataset is huge.

Comment: ok,  : drop all indexes from myTable (
I did not understand the term "indices") , insert billion of rows, then recreate indexes.. :-)  : ok :-)